# How does one retrieve the most frequently occurring keyterms from a Sphinx index?

Tags: search, sphinx

I have a Sphinx index of text files and I'd like to retrieve a list of the keyterms Sphinx found when indexing the text files, ordered, highest to lowest, by how frequently they occurred in the dataset. How do I do this?

I'd like to retrieve both the real term and the stem if possible.

I'm using the PHP api to make calls to the index.

Below are my Sphinx.conf settings for this index:

```
source srcDatasheets
{
    type                = mysql
    sql_host            = localhost
    sql_user            = user
    sql_pass            = pass
    sql_db              = db
    sql_port            = 3306

    sql_query           = \
         SELECT id, company_id, title, brief, content_file_path \
         FROM datasheets

    sql_attr_uint       = company_id
    sql_file_field      = content_file_path
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM datasheets WHERE id=$id
}


index datasheets
{
    source              = srcDatasheets
    path                = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/datasheetsStemmed
    docinfo             = extern
    charset_type        = sbcs
    morphology          = stem_en
    min_stemming_len    = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot retrieve keyword density directly from a live index with Sphinx.  The data is not stored in a way that allows this.  Here is [a response from the Sphinx forums](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=8041&new=1).

What you can do, however, is run the indexer with --buildstops, and --buildfreqs ([see the docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.1.html#ref-indexer)).  The indexer will output a txt file of the most frequently occurring terms and frequencies based on the settings you have in the .conf file for that index.

This processes the data set to create the list and the text file, and doesn't actually create a new searchable index.

I ran a test on an index of text files (converted pdfs) with min word length and min stemming lengths of 5 characters.  70,000 files processed in about 20 seconds (5 minutes with min character limits set to 1).